# What web font format has the highest quality?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've seen that some websites use `@font-face` but they look creepy & without anti-aliasing, But some other websites use some fonts with a very high quality, I don't know if they use OTF or TTF or SVG or what exactly, This is an [example](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/09/twitter-oauth-home-timeline-display.html).

I've looked into their source but there is like 4 font types and i can't figure out which one is being used.

Thanks

Comment: Those <b> titles look horribly blurry, I hope that's not the effect you are trying to achieve! (BTW, <b>s for titles? WTF)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three factors that affect quality display of the font:

1. **Quality of the font.**  Some fonts are poorly made, some are missing characters, some have ligature issues, etc.  I suggest testing the font across all browsers before committing to it.
2. **Browser rendering of the font.** Chrome, Safari, FF and IE display render fonts differently.
3. **Formats readable by the browser:** each also can only read a [limited number of  formats](https://web.archive.org/web/20140629033500/http://webfonts.info/browser-support-overview-june-2013). (EOT for IE, TT for pretty much everything else, including FF, and there's more).

In conclusion: web fonts are still somewhat of a dark and mysterious art. Invariably, there will be minor differences. [Find a well built font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface), and test it across your target browsers.  I think we're still very much in the trial and error phase with `@font-face`, but [there are good resources](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) to help along the way.

Comment: What about .OTF font file? Is that good to implement at web? Is it affect on web performance or memory consumption on user's device?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a special font on the web, then the format choice is pretty much made for you by the browsers, and you will need EOT, WOFF, TTF, and SVG all to be available.

A site like [FontSquirrel](http://fontsquirrel.com) will provide guidance as well as the font files themselves.

Comment: but which one has the best anti-aliasing, ( for firefox at least )

Comment: @David: Font rendering is (almost) unrelated to the font (or its format).

Comment: All of the format represents gryphs in vectors; I believe the result will be the same whatever the format is.

Comment: At one exception, SVG fonts do not properly represent kerning info due to limitations in the format.

Comment: Well the thing is, @Andrew Moore, browsers that only understand SVG only understand that!

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, due to the scope of the question, I had to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

The font quality largely depends on how the fonts are converted. You may choose to remove things that effect anti-aliasing and quality like kerning to save file size which many people do. The better the look, the bigger the size. Another factor that goes into the fonts is the host OS. They have certain ways they do things that can affect the way fonts render.

Also, this is just kind of random, but you can throw this into your code:

```
text-shadow: transparent 0 0 1px;
```

It will improve anti-aliasing, albeit only in Google Chrome for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Windows, embedded fonts using @font-face render horribly with **ClearType ON**.

Try this radical experiment: turn **ClearType OFF**, and recheck the font rendering.

While this seems to make no sense (the opposite should happen), you should find the fonts now look smooth and natural.

This happens for me and I can provide evidence if necessary. The same web page will render fine in Linux, Mac etc without doing any such OS-level tinkering. Yay Windows.

I am still trying to determine a work-around for this, because obviously you can't ask everyone looking at your website who's using Windows to turn ClearType off so your fonts will look good.

Comment: This depends on the font. My site uses some embedded fonts, and in IE7 and IE8 on Windows (and in other browsers on Windows) the fonts look fine with ClearType.

Comment: I may be mistaken but you may be talking about IE specifically. I haven't had such experiences, but if I had to guess which browser would do something like this, it'd be IE. I always use ClearType and I always use Chrome on Windows and I never see any issues like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some experimenting with a complex font on various browsers while making a web site. I have found that without exception, Firefox and Chrome just don't render the font well regardless of format. IE was limited to eot anyway. And surprisingly, Opera does the best job. Quite frankly, changing the format just didn't make much of a difference. Overall, I think browsers have a considerable way to go when it comes to rendering complex, intricate fonts.